# vscode shows postgresql query execution error but not the detail

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code, sqltools

I'm using vscode 1.74.2 with SQLTools extension v0.26.0 with postgresql 15.

when I run a query that results in an error in `psql` it returns error output in several namespaces, for example in my case when i run a function that i created the returns wrong result type, it's divided to 3 sections:

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type numeric does not match expected type integer in column 11.
CONTEXT: SQL statement "..."
```

when I run that query in vscode, it only shows the `ERROR`:

[image: postgresql query execution error]

when when I look at the SQL Console messages it shows only the error:

[image: Sql console messages error]

I want to also see the Detail of the error, how can i do that ?